# Defining a singleton in $[0, 1]$

Tags: notation

I have seen a singleton in the [0,1] set [defined as](https://youtu.be/I3zwALG19Zk?t=26m36s):

$\{b\}=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(b-1/n, b+1/n] \,\cap\,\Omega$

I am trying to learn some set theory in connection to the need for probability spaces, and their relation to $pdf$'s. Specifically, I'm having problems understanding the idea of a singleton.

I have two questions: The main one is how unequivocal the $\infty$ symbol is in the definition? In other words, isn't the cardinality of $\infty$ a loose end in that definition of singleton in the way expressed above? Sort of including the defined in the definition?

And a probably lesser relevant issue: why the open left parenthesis when the expression is closed with a bracket on the right?

Comment: It is not a definition. It is a formula, and as currently stated, it is a false formula. The definition of a singleton is "a set that contains exactly one element". But as your intervals are half-open, their intersection is going to be empty, not the singleton set $\{b\}$. If you were close the interval on both sides, then the intersection would be $\{b\}$, provided that $b \in \Omega$ as well.

Comment: Ty. So $$\{b\}=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}[b-1/n, b+1/n] \,\cap\,\Omega$$ would be correct, and given the condition you stated, a way of expressing a singleton in [0, 1], although not a definition? You couldn't say, "... we define a singleton in [0, 1] as..."?

Comment: @PaulSinclair In this case the intersection is *not* empty. In fact it is $\{b\}.$ Note $b$ lies in each of the intervals intersected.

Comment: It makes sense, but we still can't use it as a definition of a "singleton"?

Comment: @coffeemath - Gah! of course you are right. That was stupid! $b$ is in all the intervals. However, my comment about this not being a definition is correct.

Comment: It isn't stated in the question what $\Omega$ means... is it the sample space, i.e. $[0,1]$ or some superset of that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $\Omega$ was meant to represent the sample space [0, 1].

Comment: No you can't use it as a definition! "Singleton" already has an obvious reasonable generally applicable definition. Why would you even want to throw that away to use a complicated formula that only holds true in a specific condition as a "definition" instead?

Comment: OK. I get it. And what is the final say: $(\,]$ or $[\,]$?

Comment: You can use either one or even open intervals. The point is $b$ is the only point that is in all of the sets of the intersection.He uses $(]$ because that fits in with the rest of his development. Note that the notation does *not* mean $n = \infty$ is one of the intervals. It just indicates that there is no upper limit on the values of $n$.